# What is the polar coordinate equation for an Archimedean spiral with arc length known relative to theta?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

What is the equation for the radius of a polar coordinate for an Archimedean spiral with the arc length known relative to theta?

arc length: L = $\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\sqrt{(r)^2+(dr/d\theta)^2}d\theta$ ([mathworld.wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArcLength.html))

Archimedean Spiral: $r=a+b\theta^{1/c}$

Some known information for one example:

- $\theta$={$0$ to $\pi$}, L=8
- $\theta$={$0$ to 2$\pi$}, L=32
- $\theta$={$0$ to 3$\pi$}, L=72
- $\theta$={$0$ to 4$\pi$}, L=128
- $\theta$={$\pi$ to 2$\pi$}, L=24
- $\theta$={2$\pi$ to 3$\pi$}, L=40
- $\theta$={3$\pi$ to 4$\pi$}, L=56

so: L{$\theta_0$ to $\theta_1$} $=8*(\theta_1/\pi)^2 - 8*(\theta_0/\pi)^2$

and: L{$0$ to $\theta$} $=8*(\theta/\pi)^2$

but how do I get back to $r$ ? What are $a$, $b$, and $c$ ?

I was trying to use Wolfram-Alpha, but could not figure out [the antiderivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative%20%5Csqrt%7B%28r%29%5E2%2Br%27%28%5Ctheta%29%5E2%7Dd%5Ctheta) to continue semi-manually, or the solver to get to a formula for $r$ directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not look feasible (at least to me) if $c\neq 1$ (the generalized Archimedean spiral) .

If $c=1$ and then $r=a+b\,\theta$, $$L=\int\sqrt{r(\theta )^2+r'(\theta )^2}\,d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{(a+b \theta )^2+b^2} (a+b \theta )}{2 b}+\frac{1}{2} b \log
   \left(\sqrt{(a+b \theta )^2+b^2}+a+b \theta \right)$$ So, if you know two arc lengths, you need to solve two equations for the two unknowns $a$ and $b$; I do not think that the problem could be solve without numerical methods.

Using the first two values you gave, I did find solutions and I had to turn the problem into an optimization problem. The norm was minimized for $a=-1.70012$, $b=1.88222$. Recomputing the arc lengths gives $L_1=8.53$ and $L_2=31.86$.

Comment: Do I perhaps not have an Archimedean spiral?

Comment: @StephenT.Robbins. This is possible. Could you explain the problem more precisely ? Do you need to find a polar function which would provide a table of given arec lengths ? Please, clarify.

Comment: I am trying to write a small simulation program with what I had intended to be some simplified 2D movement/physics - the objects each have a velocity (speed + heading) and a single rate of acceleration (speed and/or heading change) when changing velocity. **1** The case of no acceleration is just velocity*time, **2** the case of only changing speed changes the length of the velocity vector, **3** the case of only changing heading can be calculated from the circle it would traverse if the object continued moving for long enough, which leaves me with **4** the case of changing speed and heading.

Comment: The case when the acceleration is changing both speed and heading, each at a constant rate, must traverse a spiral of some kind as it continues. I am looking for both the equation to use for my little simulation, and am generally curious what kind of spiral gets drawn when the arc length per theta is increasing linearly at a constant rate.

Comment: Since an acceleration of 2 per 2\pi results in the sequence of odd numbers as the speed at the end of each rotation {1, 3, 5, 7...}, and the sum arc length at the end of each rotation is the sequence of integer squares {1, 4, 9, 16...}, I thought it might be interesting enough to have been named after someone.